# mysql search for more than one field

Tags: c#, mysql, search, select

Hi guys I didn't find anything useful on stack overflow about the following problem.

I want to search a customer for more than one field.
I have some textboxes where I can enter my search criteria.

customers table:
name surname job
a    b       c
a    a       c
a    a       a

eg, when I search for name = a, surname = b, job = c, I want to see my first customer, if I search for name = a, I want to see every customer (the point is, if surname and job are null I can't get the name back from the query)

I want to search for the customers in my stored procedure, which has to fill a gridview.

C# code for my search button:

```
protected void btnRicerca_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.Visible = true;


    ClienteInfo CI = new ClienteInfo();
    DboUser objdbo = new DboUser();
    int id_cliente = 0;

    txtNomeCliente.Text = CI.nome_cliente;
    txtCognomeCliente.Text = CI.cognome_cliente;
    txtRagioneSociale.Text = CI.ragione_sociale;
    txtVia.Text = CI.via;
    txtCitta.Text = CI.citta;
    txtProvincia.Text = CI.provincia;
    txtCap.Text = CI.cap;
    txtNazione.Text = CI.nazione;
    txtTelefono.Text = CI.recapito_telefonico;
    txtPartitaIva.Text = CI.partita_iva;
    txtCodiceFiscale.Text = CI.codice_fiscale;
    txtEmail.Text = CI.email;
    txtPubblicaAmministrazione.Text = CI.codice_pubblica_amministrazione;
    CI.id_utente = Convert.ToInt64(Session["Id_Utente"]);

    id_cliente = objdbo.getClienteInfo(CI);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have to create the SQL Query according to the UI input values. 
As an example if some one enters values for name and surname then your SQL Query should be like

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = "a" and surname = "b";
```

And if Someone enters only the name your SQL Query should be as following.

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = "a";
```

Ideally You should manage the SQL Query from your application. I faced a similar experience and I used the Interpreter pattern to Generate The SQL Query.

Additionally it's always better to use like search for names.

ex : `SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name like "%a%"`

Comment: When building dynamic SQL in your application, ensure to make use of bind parameters to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Note, using a leading wild card with LIKE (ie, "%a%" ) will prevent the use of an index to check that field